Does this qualify as an alley?
The link in my previous post didn't work, so I deleted that post. Hopefully, this link works. (It works on my laptop.)

link

alley - a narrow passageway between or behind buildings. Similar words:
passage
passageway
alleyway
back alley
backstreet
lane
path
pathway...

Images should be included in questions. The answer/question should be self contained, users should not be forced to visit a site that may or may not be safe. Furthermore, it is easy to resize huge images, especially on a MacBook, all you need is a little patience.

@Mari-LouA Are you saying that only links for images can be unsafe?

@Mari-LouA Another very good reason is to preserve the image along with the question rather than to risk broken links.

I think the problem here is that alleys have somewhat different definitions in different countries / towns / cities etc. I'd be happy if the pathway in your image was described as an alley even though it is flanked by hedges rather than buildings. Again IMHO an alley doesn't have to be navigable by a car, paved with tarmac or bricks or stone. There are many alternative names as has already been pointed out and you could also have rear access and service road. It can also depend on the purpose for which it was constructed.

Paving stones and bricks are not cobblestone. Cobblestones are driven over but not bricks alone. Anyway, the picture shows an alley and I doubt most English speakers anywhere would doubt that.

I would say that it doesn't qualify as an alley, but reasonable people could disagree.
In the US, an alley is typically not  well-tended, and it will have a considerable amount of refuse like old hubcaps, soda cups, and broken glass; it won't be neatly bordered with shrubbery; nor will it be a paved walkway designed for pedestrians.Trash trucks often go down alleys, and delivery vehicles.
An alley is a narrow pathway (two cars won't fit abreast) behind a row of houses or a building, intended to serve utilitarian purposes such as  trash collection and delivery of goods.
An alley  (in the US) is not merely a pathway. An alley serves the specific needs of the individual buildings to which it is immediately adjacent, needs beyond mere access to those buildings by humans on foot.  And that is the missing feature that disqualifies the pathway in the photo from being called an "alley" as that word is used in the US in modern times in the context of streets (used loosely) adjacent to the side or rear of commercial and residential buildings. The shrubbery isolates the pathway from those buildings in a manner that makes the pathway unsuitable to service their utilitarian needs. It is a walkway.
The debris that accompanies the utilitarian purposes is incidental.

Seems like a significant US/UK usage difference here. Brits wouldn't normally call anything wide enough to be used by garbage trucks / dustbin lorries an "alley".

An alley can be narrower, if it is an old one dating from the days when items were delivered on carts. If it dates from after WW2, it is usually just wide enough that a vehicle will barely fit.  But we wouldn't call a shrub-lined, well-tended, neatly paved pedestrian walkway an alley.

See: https://www.alamy.com/large-overflowing-garbage-cans-in-a-back-alley-in-pittsburgh-pennsylvania-usa-image181751592.html?imageid=79632F38-B8B6-491D-999F-4022893F3C00&p=195435&pn=1&searchId=adb2b9bf0ee37da998634d8aa9cb2e50&searchtype=0

I think that might be another difference! It's true that most alleys tend to be "unkempt", but that's probably often because no-one has responsibility for maintaining them. I'm not gonna try to identify which side of the pond the written instances in Google Books come from, but "well-maintained alley" seems fine to me, whereas presumably you'll think it's somewhat oxymoronic.

@FumbleFingers - I was recently in a three-way argument about narrower passages between buildings: an alley (me), a ginnel (friend), a backs (wife).

Not quite oxymoronic but rare -- at least in the downtown section of major cities. Alleys in residential neighborhoods in smaller towns and in places where there is a high level of "civic pride" can be well-maintained.

@FumbleFingers - to me, also, it's too neat and wide to be an alley.

@MichaelHarvey: I will admit I always assume ginnels are "unkempt". But that's because I always imagine them as being the narrow bit of "no-man's land" between cramped back-to-back houses in Glasgow slums. Mind you, I remember briefly having a cat as a student living in a flat in 100% urbanized Portsmouth. Our cat just had to get by with a litter tray, but we called the footpath at the back of the building "Poop alley" because that's where everyone else took their pet to "do its business". That was all long before anyone ever thought dog walkers should carry poo bags, obviously! :(

There probably isn't even a single word for this used in the UK. There are regional variations.  In Scotland for example, a vennel, a close, or in parts of northern England ginnel. Maybe even just a pathway, which I think most people would understand. Even simply a lane.

The photo OP posted looks like a German "gasse".

@TimR Edinburgh is famous for its closes. They're usual well maintained, a bit of a tourist attraction these days.

Where I come from it's a jitty or twitchell. Note that, in a city, an alley can be a narrow passage with houses opening into it - c.f. 'Sally in our alley" (Michael's reference to Gracie Fields).

So it's just a street then??

I'd really appreciate it if someone finally answered the actual question. I know what an alley is but I was wondering whether what you see in the picture qualifies as an alley as well or is it just a small narrow street?

It is a pedestrian walkway, not a "street".

No, it's definitely not a street. It looks like a footpath providing a shortcut between two suburban streets. (In Britain, there are all kinds of dialect words for such footpaths in towns or suburbs, as discussed above).

@Idk29 - I think with the number of varying comments you've received, you're going to need to specify where it is before anyone can tell you what it is called.  What it's called seems to vary greatly between locations.

I dunno, for me a footpath is not an area with walkway-type pavers between two houses.  Footpaths are generally open on both sides or at least one side and with no buildings.

All this discussion is fascinating, but how does it answer the OP? For example, I've browsed some dictionary definitions of alley and can't find anything that makes the definition dependent on either vehicle access or levels of tidiness.

@PeterKirkpatrick  The discussion shows OP that the answer is not a simple Yes/No. And for that reason it should be helpful. The last place to go for such a question, IMO, is a dictionary.

@PeterKirkpatrick  A dictionary might provide a defensibly "correct" answer. But I doubt that it would be a helpful answer.

Merriam-Webster simply defines alley as:

3: a narrow street
especially : a thoroughfare through the middle of a block giving access to the rear of lots or buildings

(Along with other definitions that are irrelevant here, like in bowling and baseball.) To my mind, the only important quality is the narrowness. Many alleys are suitable for motor vehicles, but I don't know that this needs to be a defining quality; some are too narrow even for a single standard car. Also, although many are simply bordered by blank walls, I don't think the landscaping disqualifies this one (as long as there are houses or buildings behind the bushes).
So when is it a street instead of an alley? Well, for sure, if it's wide enough for two vehicles to pass each other, it's a street. And many places in the world have some streets that are very narrow (e.g. English country lanes), where two cars could not pass side by side, but these are often larger thoroughfares that are intended for regular frequent traffic and lead to points beyond. Alleys are usually just for the purpose of getting to something in the immediate vicinity (to the back of a house, to the next major street).
When is it a "path" instead of an alley? Well, if it doesn't connect to any street at all, for one. A footpath across the lawns of a college campus certainly isn't an "alley." We can't tell in this image what this alley/path goes from or to, and that matters. And if the primary purpose is helping pedestrians get from place to place, it's less likely to be called an alley; they're typically utilitarian.
Though the amount of dissent here should suggest it's not simple. The city of Charleston, SC has a number of famous "alleys"; this page about them interchanges the terms "alley," "alleyway," and "pathway," and we see not only cobbles but brick pavers. They vary in historical age, but clearly even in the 18th century, some were intended only for foot traffic.

OP wants to know if the place in the photo would be considered an alley nowadays. Historical alleys are not really relevant to the question.   Compare Philadelphia's Elfreth's Alley,  a neighborhood of row houses built during the 18th c. , and these houses face out onto the thoroughfare. They have hitching posts for horses by the front stoop.   https://tinyurl.com/ya94h4jm

Chambers gives ... 1. A passage, 2. A narrow lane, 3. A back lane, etc.
I would say alley definitely covers this (UK at least) and this side of the Atlantic is defintely the safest word, although there are many regional variations, as others have said. I'll just add "twitten" from my home county.

In the picture, you could call that an alley that you can't drive down.
But the issue is this:
Alleys that a car can drive down are not paved with bricks/stone-type tiles. Bricks cannot take the weight of a car, especially over time.
Alleys are usually paved with asphalt or sometimes are unpaved in which case they are a dirt road but a car can still drive down them without damaging the pounded dirt.
Since it is between two houses, we'd call it a walkway.
Motorcycle deliveries could drive over that unless prohibited by signage or a chain link.
In Europe, many old streets in old towns have cobblestone streets. Cobblestones are NOT bricks.
Oh look, also in the US and just like the picture posted by the OP in terms of design. An alley between residences. Paved with cobblestone. And this is BOSTON, today. From TRIP ADVISOR

And here's Soho with a cobblestone street, in NYC:


That picture immediately makes me think Europe.  I don't have familiarity with this type of path in the U.S.  I certainly would not call it an alley.  Walkway suits it very well in AmE.  I don't know if I agree about cars not being able to drive on the pictured path but that doesn't change what it would be called.

@EllieK It is definitely not a path, either in the States or the UK, People do not generally drive their cars over what looks like paving stones.

Path was just my generic, uncommitted name for it.  I would consider all roads, alleys, streets, expressways, two-tracks, goat paths, and walkways to be some variation of a path, with path defined as a route between places.

The OP didn't say anything about driving on it (and it's obviously too narrow). It looks to me like the typical shortcut between two streets that we have in British suburbs.

@KateBunting Sure, but such alleyways exist in the US, too.

I was in Toulouse last week, and the streets in the central city (zones apaisées)  where pedestrians and cyclists have priority, and cars have to go slowly and give way, have greyish paving tiles like in the OP's picture.

Europe is full of streets for cars that are paved with bricks.

@gotube - when I was younger, British car magazines sometimes tested cars they were were reviewing by driving them over Belgian pavé, notorious for the rough ride it provided. The blocks were actually stone; they are called 'setts' in the UK. They gave a good grip for horses' hooves, apparently. I was surprised to find they still exist in some places.

@gotube Those pavers in the picture are not bricks.

@Lambie Then why do you mention bricks in your answer? Fine. Stone, pavé, or whatever you want to call them. They're all over Europe, and they certainly do withstand the weight of cars.

@gotube If an alley is only paved with bricks, cars are generally not allowed. That is what I said.  And the bricks you mean are cobblestone.
